# What is the proper runtime for visiting all outgoing edges in an adjacency list?

Tags: terminology, graphs, asymptotics

Suppose that we have a directed graph $G = (V, E)$ represented as an adjacency list.  Suppose that we want to list all of the edges incident to some node $v \in V$.  We can do this by iterating over all the elements in the adjacency list.

My question concerns the runtime of this operation.  Is it proper to say that the runtime is $\Theta(deg^+(v))$ (since the runtime is a linear function of the outdegree of $v$)?  Or should it be $\Theta(1 + deg^+(v))$, since even if $deg^+(v)$ is zero, there is some amount of work that's still done?  Or are both of these terminologies incorrect because there is no underlying variable $n$ for which we could apply the formal definition of $\Theta$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You're right that $\Theta(\deg^+ v)$ is a bit sloppy, but it is usually understood that $\Theta(\deg^+ v)$ is actually $\Theta(1 + \deg^+ v)$. Perhaps it's better to use the more accurate $\Theta(1 + \deg^+ v)$.

You're also right that more formally a $\Theta(\cdot)$ notation should state the underlying variable, but here there is only one variable and so no confusion can arise. Also, since $\deg^+ v$ is always non-negative, the simpler definition of $\Theta(\deg^+ v)$ - there exists $C > 0$ such that the running time is at most $C \deg^+ v$ - is unambiguous. That's also how we should understand expressions like $\Theta(n + m)$, where the two variables $n,m$ are independent.

Comment: I'm thinking that the underlying variable in the $\Theta$ here would be either $n$ or $m$, the number of nodes or edges, but I'm not sure which one it would be.  The variable can't really be $v$, since we can't talk about "sufficiently large values of node $v$."  Should I put in something to clarify this?

Comment: The underlying variable is $\deg^+ v$.